# Why is my dispatch.then method running before my fetch and state changes (promise)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex

I'm using Vue router and vuex for state management (laravel in the backend).
Any time I try to log the user in through a function calling a vuex action, it will fire it's own .then's instead of resolving the promise provided by store.dispatch.

In any case, this makes my router push happen before the user is validated, which fails the redirect because the target page is protected.
**Why do the functions fire in the order that they do, and how do I make sure that the redirect happens after everything else?**

I want to redirect the user to a protected page once they succesfully login using the following code:

Login.vue:

```
function login(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  store.dispatch('login', user)
    .then(() => {
      console.log(3)
      router.push({ name: 'Dashboard' });
    })
// error catching...
```

actions.js:

```
export function login({commit}, user) {
  laravelClient.post('/login', user)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(1);
      commit('setUser', response.data);
      return response;
    })
}
```

mutations.js:

```
export function setUser (state, userData) {
    console.log(2);
    state.user.token = userData.token;
    state.user.data = userData.user;
    sessionStorage.setItem('TOKEN', userData.token);
}
```

As far as I know the console should be logging the numbers in the right order, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why it fires in the order: (3, 1, 2)

**Edit**
As answered by yoduh: the .then method on login runs immediately because I overlooked it didn't have its promise yet to wait for. Thanks!

Comment: you're not yet returning the promise from the login action so your `then()` function is running immediately.  you should do `return laravelClient.post(...)`.  Then your dispatch should wait before running its `then()`